# WSO2ESB: is there a way to capture filename from transport.vfs.ReplyFileName in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am renaming the response file to API-yyymmdd-01 in esb. The new name which I am providing is getting added as well while placing the same in the sftp remote server.
But now, I want to capture the filename which was sent to the remote directory into my esb registry so that I can increment the value 01 to 02 in next file transfer.

Can someone please help me how to capture the filename from transport.vfs.ReplyFileName in wso2 esb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all you need to do is keep count of how many files you have sent then you could use a database to do this.

Comment: no, actually I need to increment the number 01 to 02 and append the same in filename to send the file next time.

Comment: this could be achieve by having the count once and then increment it every time whenever the service runs using js. For calling the varaible which holds the data and also putting the incremented value in the same variable can be done by property mediator calling for get-property.
Also, registry the incremented variable should be created in registry as this can be used by other services as well.

Comment: There could be other ways as well. But this is how I achieved it.
Probably there could be some more enhancements to this requirement. I am working on it and would like to share later.